# Load the data from my.settings to datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, time, datetimepicker

I created 4 variables in my.settings called "Firststart" "firstend" "secondstart" "secondend" as type i picked `System.Timespan`.

I save the values from datetimepicker's to `my.settings` with this code

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.firstStart = DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay
    My.Settings.firstEnd = DateTimePicker2.Value.TimeOfDay

    My.Settings.secondStart = DateTimePicker3.Value.TimeOfDay
    My.Settings.secondEnd = DateTimePicker4.Value.TimeOfDay

    My.Settings.Save()

End Sub
```

Once i reopen the form on `formload` how can i load the values from my.settings to datetimepicker's.

Datetimepicker has a custom format like this "hh:mm"

Comment: have you tried to reverse what you have?  or what *have* you tried

Comment: i got error msg "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment" if i try to write  `DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay = My.Settings.firstStart`

Comment: How to: [Bind a Property to an Existing Application Setting Using the Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yyxh69h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Anel_Hodzic `DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay = My.Settings.firstStart` is a comparison expression.

Comment: You save time, then you load time, what do you expect the date to show? Your control is **Date** TimePicker, not just TimePicker, remember.

Comment: hold your mouse over `.TimeOfDay` and it will show you it is ReadOnly.  A DTP is an odd choice to simply get a time since it mainly acts as a MaskedEdit control.  Consider 2 NumericUpDowns - one for the hour and one for the mins, then create a TimeSpan from those values

Comment: @Neolisk i can't load time there is an error called "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment" when i try to reverse `DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay = My.Settings.firstStart`

Comment: @Anel_Hodzic: I know, my point was to get you thinking in direction of redesign. Once you realize what you want simply cannot work, maybe you can come up with a better solution. Plutonix's option sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Plutonix ok but what about if i don't use property `.TimeOfDay` which one i need to use because i can't convert Date to `TimeSpan` like this  `DateTimePicker1.Value = My.Settings.firstStart` because .`firststart` is `system.timespan` value

Comment: you can create a TimeSpan from the values from 2 NumericUpDns: `StartTime = New TimeSpan(stHr, stMin, 0)`  where stHr and StMin are the values from the 2 controls; put them back in sort of the same way `NUD1.Value = StartTime.Hour`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a Combo for the user to select which class they are defining, then 2 NumericUpDns to allow them to pick the Hour/Min for the start time.  There really isnt a need to define a End Time, that is just Start Time + 40 mins:

```
Public Const PeriodLength = 40

Dim stHr As Integer = NUD1.Value
Dim stMin As Integer = NUD2.Value

Dim StartTime As New TimseSpan(stHr, stMin, 0)
Dim EndTime As TimeSpan = StartTime.Add(New TimeSpan(0, PeriodLength, 0))
```

There isnt really a need to save EndTime either for the same reason.  **But** since you have multiple sets of these for the various Periods, a class to define a `ClassPeriod` is advised, then a `List(of ClassPeriod)` to store the start/stop time for each.

A class would allow you to write a nice clean method to determine when a class is in session or how long till it starts.  With a List(of T), you just need to loop thru the list.

The Combo would just be "Period 1", "Period 2" so you know which one is being defined and dont have to have a gazillion NUDs littering up the form.